# You have an error in your sql syntax (connection is OK)

Tags: node.js, bookshelf.js

I'm working with Node.js and Bookshelf, and I'm new to bookshelf. I made a basic code but doesn't work, I can't save.

This is the code :

```
var bookModel = bookshelf.Model.extend({
   tablename:  'book'
});

app.get('/addBook/:title/:id', function(req, res) {
if (req.params.title != '' && req.params.id != ''){
   bookModel.forge({title: 'test'}).save();
```

}

My connection works fine.

This is the error :

> Add book : undefined - 44 Unhandled rejection Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR:
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax;  check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right sy ntax to use
>   near '(`title`) values ('toto')' at line 1

I have seen that's a common message but I don't really understand. I've searched for more informations in documentation but I haven't find anything which help me.

Thanks for helping !

Comment: Can you double-check that you have the correct SQL dialect set in your db settings (```client: 'mysql'```)? If that's correct then could you set ```debug: true``` in your settings and let us know the SQL that gets generated for your code.

Comment: @KalleBjörklid I'm well using mysql option, I set debug: true and this is more friendly, this is the message : 
Add book : undefined - 44
{ __cid: '__cid1',
  method: 'insert',
  options: undefined,
  bindings: [ 'test' ],
  sql: 'insert into  (`title`) values (?)' }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property `tablename` should be `tableName` (notice the uppercase 'N'):

```
var bookModel = bookshelf.Model.extend({
   tableName:  'book'
});
```

If you look at the SQL you posted in the comment it is `insert into (title) values (?)`, which is not valid SQL as it lacks the target table name. I used this clue to spot the problem.